try to read a binary file written in c, with a program in fortran
it looks that it is a well discussd problem. but still the discussion I've found didnot help.
So, there is a Software that produce  temporary binary files. The data in each of them are a big matrix(5568 ;5568). From what I understand it save them in float 32.
Now I need to see what's in some of these binary files, so write a program in Fortran90 because it is more easy for me. But what I did , does not work !!
What's inside the Auxiliary module is not important, it just reads setups and build the good file name to open.
I thought that the type of the variable that I will use to read the binary file value by value is important, but apparently no, because I defined "R_VAL" as single or double precision (even an integer) and it always stop before I finish to fill my table, which is not good.
there is something wrong in my READ or OPEN, but I can't find what.
thanks.
So here is the code in fortran
PROGRAM MYFLOAT

    USE AUXILIARY
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CHARACTER(LEN=255) :: C255_ROOT,C255_Setup
    INTEGER :: I_TIME,I_ECH,I_LEV,I_COL,I_LIN
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I_WP = KIND(1.0) ! I_WP = KIND(1.0d0)
    INTEGER :: I_IOPAR=2222
    INTEGER :: I_iostat
    REAL(I_WP) :: R_VAL
    INTEGER :: I_VAL
!__________________________________________________________________________________________________
! START
    CALL GETARG(1,C255_ROOT)
    CALL GETARG(2,C255_Setup)
    ST_SAT%C255_ROOT=C255_ROOT
    PRINT*," [I] :: file will look like : "
    PRINT*,"     => ",C255_ROOT
    PRINT*," "
    PRINT*," [I] :: SETUPS IN : ",C255_Setup
    CALL AUXI_ReadSetupFile(C255_Setup)
    CALL AUXI_GetGEOsatDef(ST_SAT%I_ID)
    PRINT*," [I] :: TAB SIZE = (",ST_SAT%I_NLIN,";",ST_SAT%I_NCOL,";",ST_SAT%I_NLEV,")"
    DO I_TIME=1,ST_SAT%I_NTIME
        DO I_ECH=1,ST_SAT%I_NECH
            ALLOCATE(ST_SAT%RT3_MyVar(ST_SAT%I_NLIN,ST_SAT%I_NCOL,ST_SAT%I_NLEV))
            DO I_LEV=1,ST_SAT%I_NLEV
                CALL AUXI_SetInputFilename(I_TIME,I_ECH,I_LEV)
                PRINT*," [I] :: Reading Filename : ",ST_SAT%C255_InputFile    
                OPEN(UNIT=I_IOPAR,              &
                    FILE=ST_SAT%C255_InputFile, &
                    FORM="unformatted",  &
                    ACCESS='STREAM', &
                    ACTION="read",       &
                    POSITION="rewind",   &
                    IOSTAT=I_iostat )
                IF(I_iostat.ne.0)STOP " =>        Problème à l'ouverture" 
                DO I_COL=1,ST_SAT%I_NCOL
                    DO I_LIN=1,ST_SAT%I_NLIN                        
                        READ(I_IOPAR,IOSTAT=I_iostat) R_VAL 
                        IF(I_iostat.ne.0)THEN 
                            PRINT*," [T] :: I_LIN= ",I_LIN
                            PRINT*," [T] :: I_COL= ",I_COL
                            STOP " => MISSING VALUES IN MATRIX ! "
                        ENDIF
                         ST_SAT%RT3_MyVar(I_LIN,I_COL,I_LEV)=R_VAL
                    ENDDO
                ENDDO
                CLOSE(I_IOPAR)  
            ENDDO
            DEALLOCATE(ST_SAT%RT3_MyVar)
        ENDDO
    ENDDO




!__________________________________________________________________________________________________
! END
ENDPROGRAM MYFLOAT
``
the console output ::                                                                                   
  [T] :: I_LIN=         3713
  [T] :: I_COL=          155
STOP  => MISSING VALUES IN MATRIX !


Can the program read files written by a program written in another programming language than C? "From what I understand it save them in float 32." - Is it a binary file? If so, check if the C implementation and your fortran implementation use the same format for float.

Are you able to supply the code for the procedure - be it in C or whatever - that actually wrote the data file in the first place? Have you checked the physical size in bytes of the data file, and does it accord with your assumption about matrix dimensions? I trust you are aware that C and Fortran store multi-dimensional arrays in different orders.

Have you tried looking at the file with an appropriate command line tool (e.g od in Unix world) to see if it looks like you think it should?

Please try to reduce your problem. (Just try to read one file.)
You can try this C++-write/Fortran-read pair with a binary file.
When you have got this to work, increase N in the Fortran file to 5568 and simply try it with ONE of your data files.
With N=3 the data file size is entirely predictable: 9 x 4 = 36 bytes. So, if your conjecture about array size and variable type is correct your file would have size 5568 x 5568 x 4 = 124010496 bytes (which is quite large!). Of course, it is possible that your data file may have other stuff besides the array. It might even be compressed.
And there is nothing to stop you just reading the first few elements of your data file and seeing if they make some sense. You don't have to read the whole large array.
writeC.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//using TYPE = double;
using TYPE = float;
//using TYPE = int;

int main()
{
   const int N = 3;
   TYPE a[N][N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
   TYPE b[N][N];

   // Test write
   ofstream out( "test.dat", ios::out|ios::binary );
   out.write( (char*) a, N * N * sizeof( TYPE ) );
   out.close();

   // Test read
   ifstream in( "test.dat", ios::in|ios::binary );
   in.read( (char*) &b, N * N * sizeof( TYPE ) );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) cout << b[i][j] << '\t';
      cout << '\n';
   }
}

readf.f90:
program test
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none

   integer, parameter :: N = 3
!  real(real64) :: A(N,N)
   real(real32) :: A(N,N)
!  integer(int32) :: A(N,N)
   integer i, j

   open( 10, file="test.dat", form="unformatted", access="stream" )
   read( 10 ) ((a(i,j),j=1,N),i=1,N)   ! to match the C++ order
   close( 10 )

   do i = 1, N
      write( *, * ) a(i,:)
   end do

end program test


In my humble opinion, one needs to write a Minimal Working Example with C and Fortran codes and to attach resulting data file, as well as print each value from the file. Somehow, I think there are also some integer numbers in the file that indicate the matrix sizes.
